# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. For the Riemann–Stieltjes integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, riemann-integration

I am looking of a fundemental theorem of calculus for the Riemann-Stieljes integral.

The Fundamental theorem of calculus : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus ,
links differentiation to Riemann integration.

One can also define the Riemann-Stieljes integral : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Formal_definition.

I.e (for $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$) consider $$I(t)=\int_0^t f(s)dg(s) $$

If $g$ is a differentiable function then we can write

$$I(t)=\int_0^t f(s)g'(s)ds $$

and the fundemental theorem of calculus tells us that

$$I'(t)=f(t)g'(t). $$

$\textbf{Question}$ : what if $g$ is not differentiable, say $g$ is only monotonically increasing and non-negative. Then what can we say about $I'(t)$ ? Can we bound it from above?

In the above let us assume the function $f$ is a continuous and non-negative, and   Riemann-Stiejles integrable.

Comment: You can prove that $I'(t)$ exists almost everywhere.  There may be points where it does not exist under such weaker assumptions. Also you have said nothing about $f$ other than (tacitly) it is integrable in some sense.

Comment: I will edit now to include some information on $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume only that $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $g$ and $g$ is monotonically increasing on $[a,b]$.  Under these assumptions $f$ is almost everywhere continuous and $g$ is almost everywhere differentiable. We can then say that $I$ is differentiable at any point $t \in [a,b]$ where simultaneously $f$ is continuous and $g$ is differentiable, and $I'(t) = f(t) g'(t)$.

Proof:

Since a Riemann-Stieltjes integrable function must be bounded there exists finite $m,M$ such that $m = \inf_{s \in [t,u]}f(s) $ and $M = \sup_{s \in [t,u]}f(s) $, and since $g$ is increasing,

$$m[g(u)-g(t)] \leqslant I(u) - I(t) =\int_t^uf \, dg \leqslant M[g(u) - g(t)]$$

Thus,

$$m \frac{g(u) - g(t)}{u-t} \leqslant \frac{I(u)-I(t)}{u-t} \leqslant M\frac{g(u) - g(t)}{u-t}$$

Taking the limit as $u \to t$ and applying the squeeze theorem we get $I'(t) = f(t) g'(t)$. Note that $m,M \to f(t)$ as $u \to t$ follows from the continuity of $f$ at $t$.

This result holds more generally if $g$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: In fact, in what i'm working with, I do have that $g$ has bounded variation. - Thanks, is there a particular source for R-S integration that you usually use out of interest?

Comment: @Monty: I would look at Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis and Apostol, Mathematical Analysis.  Apostol IMO is better.

Comment: Yes I was looking through Rudin,  I will look at Apostol too!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the result holding more generally if $g$ is of bounded variation?

Comment: @Monty: If $g$ is of bounded variation, then it can be written as a difference of two monotonically increasing functions $g = p-q$ and $I'(t) = f(t)[p'(t) - q'(t)]$ at points where both $p$ and $q$ are differentiable.